# Incorrect marketing cloud aar packaging?

Tags: marketing-cloud, android

In the aar from marketingcloudsdk is a class packaged as `a.a` which currently leads to a duplicate class error when building our application... because another library we just updated does the very same thing.

Would you please take a look?

[image: Android studio gradle import]

Edit:
Gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.0.3"
}
```

Maven:

```
maven {
    url "https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/repository"
}
```

Comment: Please share your `app/build.gradle` (or at least the dependencies section of it)

Comment: I added just the one dependency, we have a lot of dependencies and most of them are from internal projects. I do not think it is relevant though, the content of the aar can be checked with just the maven url and unpacking the aar manually. If you have the mappings.txt it would be interesting to check which class ends separated from the rest of the packages.

Comment: It's a Kotlin extension function for JSONObject that is in a standalone file (not a class) and Proguard is doing something odd with it.  Kicker is, that code has been there for a very long time :)  Thank you (unfortunately) for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: Would you mind opening a support request and having them at-mention me, please?

Comment: I am not directly a "customer" from salesforce. I don't have an account or anything like that, but I will pass the message on to someone who does.

Comment: Version 8.0.4 has been released and addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An updated `r8` is obfuscating a Kotlin extension function that resides outside of a "class" file incorrectly.  A fix is being prepared for release.

UPDATE 20211123 -- Version 8.0.4 released to address this issue.